# What type of hosting to buy for a video sharing website?

Tags: video, hosting, video-streaming

I would like to make a website where users would be able to upload videos and pictures for others to see, like YouTube/Flickr, but I'm not sure what type of hosting I would need for such a site. Could I use a Hostgator dedicated server with Amazon S3 storage for the videos? Or could I get away with less? Could I somehow start off small and then get more serious if needed in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "start off small and then get more serious if needed in the future", then you need something that can be scaled. Look at Amazon's web services or maybe Rackspace.

A big problem with video websites is bandwidth. And, you want to make the "experience" an enjoyable one. You don't want the users to have to wait three minutes for buffering.

How big/large would the videos be? A few MB? A few hundred MB? A few GB?

Comment: I was thinking of Amazon S3 for the storage, and dedicated hosting from GoDaddy. Would that not be enough for a smooth experience? I like Amazon because from what it looks like I only pay for what I use. I would think ~5 mins would be the upper-bound on video times, but most would probably be 1-3 mins, maybe in the couple hundred megs?

Comment: Well, if you want to "only pay for what I use", and you plan on using Amazon S3, why not use [Amazon's EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) for the website?

Comment: Just looked into EC2 and it looks like that's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is bandwidth, latency and price. distribute videos can be very expensive, in many aspects. You need be fast, and it is not cheap. You can start with a simple solution in your VPS and consider something like Akamai later.